# Suggested Mailbox in Apple Mail ("Move to ..." button) sometimes works, sometimes not

Tags: mail.app, email

A great improvement is the "Move to ..." button in Apple mail, which suggests (or predicts) a mailbox to move the mail to.

Now, for some emails, Apple Mail has learnt the correct mailbox, bur for other emails, it does not learn it.
For instance, I am getting emails from a specific address and I am always moving them to the same folder, but Apple Mail does learn to not suggest the mailbox.

Does anyone have ideas as to why this features sometimes works, sometimes not? 
Is there anything I could do to make it work, especially for those clear-cut cases?

Comment: As an alternative, try smart mailbox or using Rules. Also, from a brief glance on my suggestions, I think it depends on mailing lists, and content of the mail, more than the sender.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Actually, I am using Rules for some emails, but for most of the incoming emails, I need to read them first before they can go into their respective mailboxes.